# Is It Legal For Amateurs To Investigate Crimes / Cold Cases?

Tags: is-x-legal, investigation, crime

As someone who is not a member of law enforcement, I have an interest in possibly investigating unsolved crimes and cold cases near me, including missing persons. I am in Michigan, in case jurisdiction would play a large role in the answer.

Is it legal for me to do so without informing the local authorities? By "investigate" I mean reviewing evidence, interviewing witnesses, and looking for new evidence.

I understand there are likely a lot of factors to consider (especially since I would not have any legal authority to trespass while looking for evidence or harass witnesses). And I also understand it is likely discouraged by LE for safety reasons.

Would it simply come down to *I can do anything I want as long as I don't break any laws*?

**Bonus Question:** Is it possible to legally access original case files or online forensic databases (fingerprints, DNA, etc).

Comment: "_I can do anything I want as long as I don't break any laws?_" — that's _universally_ true. Guess your question is essentially _whether_ you'd be breaking any laws.

Comment: *"reviewing evidence, interviewing witnesses, and looking for new evidence."* - The word you're looking for is 'journalist'

Comment: Are there limits on what is legal? That depends on the Jurisdiction - which is**where** you are. In the PRC, many actions done to investigate as a private person can be construed into a subversion charge against them - which is a capital crime I was told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it legal for me to do so without informing the local authorities?

Yes.

> Would it simply come down to I can do anything I want as long as I
> don't break any laws?

Yes.

> Is it possible to legally access original case files or online
> forensic databases (fingerprints, DNA, etc).

This varies by jurisdiction and type of information.

In most cases, investigative files of law enforcement are protected from mandatory disclosures under open records laws or the freedom of information act.

Likewise, most governmental forensic databases of biometric information are not open for use by the general public.

But there are exceptions, and sometimes law enforcement will make select information available to members of the general public in their discretion, in order to facilitate their ability to solve cold cases with crowd sourcing.